# Lazy Loading Geofire results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, geofire

I am using Geofire and Firebase to store users location and get nearby users. However, when I use `geoQuery.on("key_entered", ...` to get the users close by, I would like to lazy load this data. i.e. get the first 10 results, then get the next 10 results etc.

I am not sure how to do this as I don't see a way via Geofire's documentation. Can anyone assist me with achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to limit the keys based on the number returned.

If you want fewer keys to be returned you will have to use a smaller distance in the query.

If you want to only process the first 10 keys, you can keep a counter and stop processing after you've handled 10.